# AWK determine if all characters in a string are identical?

Tags: string, awk

I'm trying to determine if all characters in a string are the same in AWK.  Here's my current code but there has to be a more succinct way, no?

```
same = 1;
for (i = 1; i < length(s); i++)
        if (substr(s, i, 1) != substr(s, i+1, 1))
            same = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [regular expression](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) match operation:

```
   Pattern="^" substr(s, 1, 1) "+$"
   if (s ~ Pattern) print "match!"
```

The match pattern reads: "match any string which consists of one or more characters  equal to the first character of s from start to end".

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` approach

```
awk '{line=$0; 
      print length(line)==gsub(substr(line,1,1),"",line)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

All the same character:

```
awk '$0 !~ "[^"substr($0,1,1)"]"'
awk '$0 ~ "^"substr($0,1,1)"+$"'
```

At least one different character:

```
awk '$0 ~ "[^"substr($0,1,1)"]"'
awk '$0 !~ "^"substr($0,1,1)"+$"'
```